# Associate values of one list with the ones of another list with linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have two lists, one holding some information about customers and one other table with some more information about the financial status of a customer (1-to-1 relationship).

**Customer table:**

- Id
- Name
- Address

**Fincance table:**

- Id
- CustomerId
- Salary

My goal is to link each salary to the list of customers (not all customers have an associated recored in the finance table).
I am receiving all my customers and finances like this:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers= await _customerService.GetCustomers();
IEnumerable<CustomerDTO> customerDTOs = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Customer>, IEnumerable<CustomerDTO>>(kunden); // Map to CustomerDTO which contains a property for salary
IEnumerable<Finance> finances= await _financeService.GetFinances();
```

**Example:**

```
+----+-----------+---------+     +----+------------+--------+
| Id |   Name    | Address |     | Id | CustomerId | Salary |
+----+-----------+---------+     +----+------------+--------+
|  1 | Microsoft | foo 1   |     |  1 |          1 | 8,650$ |
|  2 | Apple     | foo 2   |     |  3 |          2 | 7,880$ |
|  3 | Testla    | foo 3   |     +----+------------+--------+
+----+-----------+---------+
```

Note: I am mapping `Customer` to a `CustomerDTO` which has a field `Salary`. That field should be filled with the ones of the Finance table. I cannot change the design of my tables and there is a reason behind the table design which I am not going to talk about due to simplicity. **I am just interested if it is possible to use linq to do this kind of operation.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible - you have the list of `customers` and the list of `salaries`.
To join them manually, you can just do

```
customers.Select(x=> new {
                          x.Id, 
                          x.Name, 
                          x.Address, 
                          Salary = salaries.SingleOrDefault(y=>y.CustomerId==x.Id)?.Salary
                           }).ToList();
```

This will create a new list with the info joined.

You can also do a straight join as well:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins

Comment: I found out another way of achieving this as I explained below. @Matt

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it besides the way that Matt explained is like this:

```
finances.ToList().ForEach(x => customerDTOs.Where(y => y.Id == x.CustomerId).First().Salary = x.Salary);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do with Left outer join as well:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

From above link:

You have the list of customers and the list of Finance so Can you please try this:

```
var abc = from c in customers
                  join fa in Fincance on c.Id equals fa.CustomerId into fin
                  from fa in fin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new
                  {
                      c.Id,
                      c.Name,
                      c.Address,
                      salary = fa != null ? fa.Salary : null
                  };
```